# MS Access Report "per detail" formatting and accessing in VBA

Tags: ms-access, formatting, report

Im trying to access MS Access Report detail instances of a report page in VBA so i can do some formatting on each entry in the report.

Im not sure if this is possible as im trying to create a report which shows positive and negative differences between specific text boxes of 2 detail sections (only 2 will allways be visible on a report page).

I know how to code colours and the differences - i would just like to know how and if i can access those instances of text boxes in the detail sections so i can compare their content.

Im not a big fan of VBA so im not much knowledgable on the subject

Any help much apreciated!

Comment: I think no-one will be able to answer your question as what you are trying to achieve is not clear. What do you really mean by your are _"trying to create a report which shows positive and negative differences between specific text boxes of 2 detail sections"_?  Include a screenshot or some other information to explain your issue in more details.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, the best way would be to use the "Format" event of the report's *detail section*. This event is fired every time a record is formatted to be displayed in this section, so `Me.txtMytextcontrol.Value` should give you access to that very control at that time.